# Overflow in BoxDecoration in Gridview Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, gridview

In this gridview i put image and text in column surrounded buy boxdirecction but sometime if image size is bigger or text is bigger and come to second line then overflow in bottom occur

here is my code please suggest some way to solve this

```
Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10,left: 15,right: 10),
                    child: GridView.count(
                      crossAxisCount: 3,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      children: List.generate(25, (index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                          child: Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(
                                width: 1.0,
                                color: Color(0xFFF9AD16),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                  Image.asset(
                                    "images/register_top_logo.png",
                                    height: 50,
                                    width: 50,
                                  ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 10,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "Categoryjkjkj",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color(0xFF0066CB),
                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Here is screen

[image: screen]

Please suggest some good way to solve this

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the `childAspectRatio` of the `GridView` ? In order to get the desired aspect ration you have to set it to the (width / height)  of your card.

Comment: no, I am not aware about childAspectRation if you have any knowledge about that please guide me how to do it

Comment: If my answer helped you with the problem specified in your original post, please accept it. If not, provide more detail as to why it does not. @mayur.p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Expanded(
 child:  Text(
         "Categoryjkjkj",
         style: TextStyle(
         color: Color(0xFF0066CB),
         fontSize: 20.0,
             ),
           ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add wrap *Expanded* widget along the Image as well as Text widgets. To fit large text *FittedBox* Widget is helpfull.

```
children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset(
                      "images/img.jpeg",
                      height: 50,
                      width: 50,
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: FittedBox(
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        child: Text(
                          "Categoryjkjkj",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xFF0066CB),
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
```

Comment: i put it but text become small if text is too large in length

Answer (score 0):

The `childAspectRatio` determines `height` of items in the `GridView` widget. The `childAspectRatio` is calculated using : `(width / height)` of the child widget of the `Gridview`.

I added a demo using your code as an example:

```
class StackOver extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, left: 15, right: 10),
        child: GridView.count(
          // give the gridview a childAspectRation
          childAspectRatio: 80 / 120, // (ITEM_WIDTH / ITEM_HEIGHT)
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
          mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: List.generate(
            25,
            (index) {
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      width: 1.0,
                      color: Color(0xFFF9AD16),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset(
                        "images/register_top_logo.png",
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Categoryjkjkj",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF0066CB),
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try wrapping Text with Expanded Widget